# Docker (Compose) client connects to Kafka too early

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to run Kafka with Docker and Docker Compose. This is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: "wurstmeister/zookeeper"
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    build:
      context: "./services/kafka"
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "0.0.0.0"
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

  users:
    build:
      context: "./services/users"
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    ports:
      - "4001:4001"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: "develop"
      ZOOKEEPER_HOST: "zookeeper"
      ZOOKEEPER_PORT: "2181"
    volumes:
      - "./services/users:/service"
```

The users service only tries to connect (using kafka-node in Node.js) and listens on a topic and publishes one message to it every time it is ran.

The problem is that I keep getting Connection Refused errors. I am using Dockerize to wait for the kafka port to be available in the `Dockerfile` with the line `CMD dockerize -wait tcp://kafka:9092 node /service/index.js`.

It waits for the port to be available before starting the users container and this system works, but it is not at the right time. It seems that Kafka is opening the 9092 port before it has elected a leader.

When I run Kafka first and let it start completely and then run my app, it runs smoothly.

How do I wait for the correct moment before starting my service?

Answer (score 17):

Try the docker-compose version 2.1 or 3, as it includes an [`healthcheck`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/healthcheck) directive.
See "[Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854997/6309)" as an example.

You can:

```
depends_on:
  kafka:
    condition: service_healthy
```

And in kafka add:

```
healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", ...]
    interval: 30s
    timeout: 10s
    retries: 5
```

with a `curl` command for instance which would test if kafka has elected a leader.

Comment: @Industrial They did indeed! Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (for this answer, and for the answers to your other questions)

Comment: Is there a `curl` command to test if kafka has elected a leader?  Can you even `curl` kafka?

Comment: @c24w All I know is http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html (I see "leader" mentioned when inspecting topic metadata: http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html#inspect-topic-metadata)

Comment: @VonC I came across kafka-rest while Googling, but was hoping for a simple way to ask kafka for the leader by hitting it directly.

Comment: according to docker-compose documentation : "Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on"  I wanted to use dockerize, but cant see how to use dynamic ports with it.

Comment: could you give the full "test" value?

Comment: @JosiahCoad 4 years later, I believe this test CMD value would be similar to the curl commands you see in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854997/6309

Comment: You can use some of the scripts available in Kafka itself.  For example: `healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "kafka-topics.sh", "--list", "--bootstrap-server", "host.docker.internal:9092"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 4`

Comment: @JamesJones I don't see those in https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/search?q=healthcheck&type=issues though.

Comment: those scripts are part of the kafka distro. confirmed it's there `docker run -it bitnami/kafka kafka-topics.sh --version`

Answer (score 4):

A full example; this is what I use in docker compose.

tldr; use a kafka healthcheck
`["CMD", "kafka-topics.sh", "--list", "--zookeeper", "zookeeper:2181"]`

- integration test app depends on kafka
- app depends on kafka
- kafka depends on zookeeper

Since the integration test and the app are starting at the same time, I think this helps with total execution time.
Also, both are starting after kafka's healthcheck is passing.

```yaml
version: '2.1'

services:

  my-integration-tests:
    image: golang:1.16
    volumes:
      - myapp:/app
    command: go test -tags=integration -mod=vendor -cover -v --ginkgo.v --ginkgo.progress --ginkgo.failFast
    depends_on:
      kafka:
        condition: service_healthy

  my-app:
    image: local/my-app
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      kafka:
        condition: service_healthy

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
    expose:
      - "2181"
    tmpfs:
      - /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/data

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    expose:
      - 9092
    tmpfs:
      - /kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://localhost:9094,OUTSIDE://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9094,OUTSIDE://:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      LOG4J_LOGGER_KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_LOGGER: DEBUG, authorizerAppender
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "kafka-topics.sh", "--list", "--zookeeper", "zookeeper:2181"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
```